# How to replace backslash in AS3 Flash?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to replace the backslashes of the url/path to get the file name of the swf:

```js
var path:String = "C:\Test\myswf.swf"

var swfURL:String = path.replace(/\\/gi, "/");

var swfFileName:String = path.slice(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, path.length).replace(".swf", "");
```

But it doesn't works. The response is: 'C:Testmyswf.swf'. It's doesn't replace the string path. How can i do it?

Comment: For future debugging strategies, if the _output_ of a function isn't what you're expecting, always make sure the _input_ is what you think it is, so that you can find where exactly the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to escape the backslashes within your URL string:

```
var path:String = "C:\\Test\\myswf.swf"
```

Comment: It's great! But, how i do this with the `stage.loaderInfo.url`?

Comment: Try assigning stage.loaderInfo.url as the value of your path variable and see what happens. If you're planning to run this code over the web you might be better testing locally on a webserver because the regular expression you have at the moment isn't going to work in a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\\([^\\.]+)\.
```

Then get $1

Comment: Care to be a bit more clearer? Apply this to the OP's context, it will be easier on him (and other users too) to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem by "performing crazy" with the code below:

```
var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("\\d"+stage.loaderInfo.url, "gi");

var idswf:String = reg.toString().replace(/\\/g, "/");

idswf = idswf.split("/")[idswf.split("/").length-2].replace(".swf", "");
```

It may not be the best solution, but it worked well for me and can work for other people...